# Select Multiple Data Groups with jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to select multiple data groups using jQuery. I currently do it like this.

```
function unselectAll() {
$('[data-group="ab"]').prop('checked', !1);
$('[data-group="cd"]').prop('checked', !1);
$('[data-group="ef"]').prop('checked', !1);
$('[data-group="gh"]').prop('checked', !1);
}
```

How do I combine all of these in to one line. Thank you for taking the time to looking in to this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to select all groups at once you can use:

```
$('[data-group]').prop('checked', !1);
```

If you have different groups to address, you can select something like this (comma separated selection for each group):

```
$('[data-group="ab"], [data-group="cd"], [data-group="ef"], [data-group="gh"]').prop('checked', !1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include multiple rules in the same set like you would in CSS - by using a comma. Your code rewritten would look like:

```
function unselectAll() {
$('[data-group="ab"],[data-group="cd"],[data-group="ef"],[data-group="gh"]').prop('checked', !1);
}
```